# Pandas Column Min - Variable Window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the min/max of a column with a rolling window that is based on another column. Usually for min/max rolling I'd use:

```
.rolling(window=periods).min()
```

However I want the 'periods' to reference another DataFrame column instead of being fixed. Is this possible?

Desired Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Do you need `cummin` per groups like `df.groupby(df['Period'].eq(1).cumsum())['Gap'].cummin()` ?

Comment: Potentially, what does the .eq(1) element of that line do? @jezreal

Comment: It create groups by starting `Period == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`GroupBy.cummin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummin.html) per groups starting `Period == 1`:

```
df['Min'] = df.groupby(df['Period'].eq(1).cumsum())['Gap'].cummin()
```